# iOS Enterprise program violation?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

I've been doing research about the enterprise program and something still isn't clear with me.
The apple guidelines say that when you purchase a enterprise license you can use this license for the following:

- Distribution outside the App Store
- Distribution to unlimited devices
- No review from Apple necessary

The program is intended for distribution within your enterprise. But aside these concrete rules I also read it's allowed to put the software on the devices that are owned by the company. That doesn't explicitly says that the user of the application has to be employed at the company.

**My question is**: Is it a violation of the rules when the company owns the device but customers/clients uses it?

Regards,

Leon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ask the Apple Enterprise team this question to be sure. Note that the apps phone home from the device to Apple (if possible) to verify that the Enterprise license is still valid and thus records what devices are using this. However there are no registration of the devices so it's up to Apple to challenge any questionable practices. Always best to ask Apple.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I hoped that somebody here could provide me with a "quick" answer regarding the fact that a response from Apple takes a very long time :-). Thx!